# How update data in Model Maching learning in IBM watson studio

Tags: model, ibm-watson, watson-studio

I have the following question.

I am training a machine learning model in IBM watson studio. It is in process already having the model deployed. Is it possible to change the data without having to redeploy it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you change your training data, you will get a new model. Then you need to deploy it again as it is not the same model.